# Flag variable with user input to quit

Tags: java, loops

I have a program that is supposed to simulate a game of poker in java. I have a method class called Poker and a check class called CheckPoker which calls the methods in the method class. I haven't even been able to check if the algorithmic part works because while asking if the user would like to switch out any cards. The loop should quit after 5 cards have been entered or if the user enters "1" but in running the program, the for loop doesn't quit until 5 card values have been entered and then throws a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 56" error. I have tried a for loop, a while loop, a do-while loop, but none have seemed to work thus far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Poker {
    private String[] deck = {
            "D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8","D9","D10","DJ","DQ","DK","DA",
            "C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10","CJ", "CQ","CK","CA",
            "H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6","H7","H8","H9","H10","HJ", "HQ","HK","HA",
            "S1","S2","S3","S4","S5","S6","S7","S8","S9","S10","SJ", "SQ","SK","SA"};
    private List<String> hand = new ArrayList<>();
    public Poker(){
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(deck));
    }

    public void playGame(){
        System.out.print("The first five cards are: ");
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            System.out.print(deck[i] +", ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        int k = 0;
        String j;
        List<String> discard = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter up to 5 cards you want to get rid of (1 to quit): ");
        while (k<5) { //this is the loop I'm having trouble with
            j = in.next();
            if(!j.equals("1")){
                j = in.next();
                discard.add(j);
                k++;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        List deckList = Arrays.asList(deck);
        String[] discard1 = discard.toArray(new String[0]);
        for(int l = 0; l<k; l++){
            int m = deckList.indexOf(discard1[l]);
            String n = deck[m];
            deck[m] = deck[l+5];
            deck[l+5] = n;
        }
        System.out.print("Your new hand is: ");
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            System.out.print(deck[i] +", ");
            hand.add(deck[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

Comment: What are you supposed to enter to "Enter up to 5 cards you want to get rid of "? The card name in deck?

Comment: B.Go Yes, for example, if your hand is D3, DQ, H8, HQ, C3 then you should be able to enter C3 then 1 and your new hand would be D3, DQ, H8, HQ, and whatever is next in the deck.

Comment: You call `j = in.next();` twice, you're adding an unknown 2nd token in discard, not what you tested in if, not what you asked to discard

Comment: you need to lower that line after setting discard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. It seems you were grabbing two cards per iteration and not capturing them all in the ArrayList.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter up to 5 cards you want to get rid of (1 to quit): ");
while (k<5) { //this is the loop I'm having trouble with
    j = in.nextLine();
    if(j.equals("1") {
        break;
    }
    discard.add(j);
    k++;
}
```